# I want to use CSSs, JSs and images over https on http pages

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I want to use CSSs, JSs and images over https on http pages on apache. 
How and what sould I configure for use the some link on HTTPS as well as HTTP like...

```
src='//www.site.com/_js/script.js'
```

And what is the right directory structure for this kind of use? Right now I'm using this...

```
/domain.com
    /private_html
        /js
        /images
        /css
    /public_html
        /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

On a page with the url of `proto://host/some/file.ext`, the following link `src='/_js/script.js'` will be processed by browser as if it was `src='proto://host/_js/script.js'`.

Comment: but some browsers wont load https:/site/_js/script.js file from http and some of them just trows errors or warnings

Comment: With `src='/_js/script.js'`, when the `http://host/some/file.ext` is opened in browser, the `http://host/_js/script.js` will be loaded; when the `https://host/some/file.ext` is opened in browser, the `https://host/_js/script.js` will be loaded

Comment: Oh, it seems i didn't fully understood your question. So you have some html pages served through http, and want to serve images through https? Why?

Comment: well I dont want to serve them from https but I dont want to place same image or js to two difrent directory either. :) one for https and one for http...

Comment: With the current configuration, do you serve different content (html, images, etc) over https as opposed to http? What prevents you from serving both https and http requests in a single VirtualHost?

Comment: Yes but the different content that I served use the some js css e.g AND I can't reach the `private_http/_js/file.js` from `http://www.site.com/_js/file.js`
I'm not useing a virtual host.

Comment: Why do you serve different content based on the protocol? And what is `private_http`; do you mean `https://www.site.com/`?